# UITextView in For Loop missing argument

Tags: xcode, swift, for-loop, uitextview

Xcode is throwing a `missing argument for parameter textContainer` in call for the `textShown1 = CustomTextView` line. I'm curious as to why it throws the error only inside the `for` loop, but outside it doesn't.

```
for i in 1...paragraphCount {
    // Missing 'argument textContainer in call below', various other errors like 'consuective statements on a line must be separated by ;'
    textShown1 = CustomTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 125 + (50*i)), width: CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-400))

    paragraphs.append(textShown1)
    self.view?.addSubview(textShown1)

}

    textShown1 = CustomTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-400))
```

I thought that the it may cause issues for not being a `CGFloat` also, but after trying to convert it it still throws an error. I changed the `CustomTextView` to `UITextView` just to have the code less confusing:

```
for i in 1...8 {

    var converted: CGFloat = CGFloat(i)
    // Missing 'argument textContainer in call below', various other errors like 'consuective statements on a line must be separated by ;'
    textShown1 = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (50 * converted)), width: CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-400)

    paragraphs.append(textShown1)
    self.view?.addSubview(textShown1)

}
```

Comment: please show us your CustomTextView class.

Comment: Hey Christian, that class has nothing in it just removes firstResponder from the UITextView class. Edited the question

Comment: What is paragraphs here?? what is its datatype

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now it works. You had some errors in your code.

Comment: ah just saw it. yea the CGRect was the problem. Thanks! I accepted lyndsey's answer though already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 125 + (50*i)), width: CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), height: CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-400)
```

should be

```
CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(125 + (50*i)), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGFloat(CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-400))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is missleading. Your problem is the `i`. It's an `Int`. You have to cast it to `CGFloat` to make it work.

```
var converted:CGFloat = CGFloat(i)
textShown1 = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 50 * converted, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - CGFloat(400)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Still throwing the error though :( amended question with the converted i - still throwing the error.

Comment: What is paragraphs here?? what is its datatype